# how to pass viewbag data from view to another component template that I call in this view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, viewbag

I have a `ViewBag` data from the controller that I get in the `View`. However, my view is made of multiple components and a component (Which is a `html` template and relevant `JavaScript`), has a placeholder for this data where I need to display this data.

How would I pass this `@ViewBag.Data` to the placeholder in another `view` (Template here). ?

Or, would it be easy to consider passing the data from `Controller` to another `view`?

Please help me with a sample snippet

Comment: Could you please provide some code to help better understand the question?

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you can do this by using the same controller for your second view, like writing `ng-controller="SameController"` or creating an angular service or factory and sharing your data between two different controllers that each one serves a specific template/view.

Comment: Cosmin, thank you, but how to implement it? I am new to angular, please help me with a sample code. Also, it should be a good design approach to do the way you advise?

Comment: I just realized, I can not use same controller as we have every module, every controller tied up independently for every view and templates

Comment: I am calling one other template from one of the other template view and hence this problem

Comment: @Learner I was referring with sharing data to something like this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

Comment: Cosmin, thank you so much, my Lead came and helped me quick, in the project method that we follow. He did it in just within a minute. Thank you so much :) Actually a whole hierachy was involved, but just a field passing data across :) I am new to angular :)

Comment: I gave you a up vote and marked as you were happy to help me