# passing values from view to javascript file

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-directive

how to pass value of `ViewBag` from view to a javascript file that is nothing but the angular controller module file?

I have a `ViewBag` with data as

`@ViewBag.Data`

Answer (score 1):

I gave an answer to your first question related to this here:

[how to pass viewbag data from view to another component template that I call in this view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990874/how-to-pass-viewbag-data-from-view-to-another-component-template-that-i-call-in/38005196#38005196)

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden field with the value of `@ViewBag.Data`, then you can access it on javascript `document.getElementById("field_id").value`